# How do I make a macro to look up a number in a cell, copy specific values, then paste values into a row with the corresponding number?

Tags: excel, copy, lookup, paste, vba

The title pretty much says it, but for an example... I start with something like this:

```
'   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
1   3
2
3      0  0  0  5  7  3
4
5
6   1
7   2
8   3'
```

Then when I run the macro, it will look up the value in A1 (3), copy the values in range B3:G3, then paste the values into range B8:G8.

Note that the values in row 3 will be calculated from a formula, but the values it pastes into row 8 need to be numeric so they won't change when the values in row 3 are updated.

I searched and found the following code that might work, but I'm not quite sure how to set it up:

```
`Sub FindCopy()
Dim rFound As Long

On Error Resume Next
With Sheet1.Range("A:A")
    Set rFound = .Find(What:="Value-to-find-here", _
    After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
    Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If rFound Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    rFound(1, 3).Copy Range("PasteHere")
End With
End Sub`
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Is the source data in row `3` (`B3:G3`) because `A1` = 3? Or is the destination range `B8:G8` because the value of `A1` matches `A8`? or both, or somthing else?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to find the row whose value in column `A` matches `A1`, and copy values from `B3:G3`  into that row, try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim rDest As Range
    With Worksheets("YourWorksheetName")
        var = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        ' Deal with invalid data in A1
        If IsError(var) Then Exit Sub
        If IsEmpty(var) Then Exit Sub
        If Not IsNumeric(var) Then Exit Sub

        Set rDest = .Columns(1).Find( _
          What:=var, _
          After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
          Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        ' Only copy if Find got a result  
        If Not rDest Is Nothing Then
            rDest.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Value = .Range("B3:G3").Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very close thank you! Now I just need to play with it to account for different cell references than what I specified in my OP.

Comment: One more thing... Is there a way to make a pop-up dialogue asking if they're sure they want to copy values, and then another one that will ask them if they want to overwrite values if the cells that we're pasting the data to aren't blank?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it :

```
Sub FindCopy()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("YourSheetName")
Dim rowToCopy As Long
rowToCopy = ws.Cells(1, 1)
ws.Range(ws.Cells(rowToCopy, 2), ws.Cells(rowToCopy, 7)).Copy ws.Range("B8:G8")
End Sub
```

What you found wasn't really related to what you needed.